# Error involving subprocess.py while building Android for a RK3066 device

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, java-6

I get an error when building Android from source which I have not tinkered with and it should really by all means work (I'm quite certain I've got all the libs installed, Java and Python in the correct version). Error messages go as follows:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1065, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1061, in main
    options.optimize_generation)
  File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 996, in GenerateJNIHeader
    jni_from_javap = JNIFromJavaP.CreateFromClass(input_file, namespace)
  File "../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 507, in CreateFromClass
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
make: *** [out/target/product/rk3066/obj/GYP/shared_intermediates/ui/gl/jni/Surface_jni.h] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I'm not really a specialist, so maybe the information I have provided is not complete. In this case - let me know.

Comment: On what OS are you trying to do this, are you using an IDE, and what commands did you type?

Comment: ============================================  
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL  
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.4.2  
TARGET_PRODUCT=rk3066  
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng  
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release  
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=  
TARGET_ARCH=arm  
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon  
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9  
HOST_ARCH=x86  
HOST_OS=linux  
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.13.0-37-generic-x86_64-with-LinuxMint-17.1-rebecca  
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release  
BUILD_ID=KOT49H  
OUT_DIR=out  
============================================  
  
Command used:  
$ make -j4  
  
I'm not using an IDE, building in a terminal emulator.

Comment: @KrzysiekSetlak Did you solved your problem?

Comment: Nope, laid it off until later as I can't think of any solution, I don't know what is wrong at all :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At line 507 in file external/chromium_org/base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py

```
   p = subprocess.Popen(args=['javap', class_name], 
                     cwd=os.path.dirname(class_file), 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It seems you don't have javap available in your PATH

If you have installed the jdk1.6.0_45 in usr/lib/jvm, then you can run this command

```
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javap javap /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javap 1
```